# Merging three arrays with respect to their indices to single array

Tags: c#

I have three arrays each having different data. I want to join them as a single array where element at 0 index in each array must be at the same index in the newly created array.

For example:

```
 arr1[0]="Trailor";
 arr1[1]="Total Recall";

 arr2[0]="Life of Pi";
 arr2[1]="BDRIP";


 arr3[0]="350MB";
 arr3[1]="4.37GB"
```

Just I want the new array with any dimensions but the elements in above arrays should be accessible through the loops.

I want to print the elements in a table like below:

```
 <table>
      <thead>
            <tr>
                 <td>Film Title</td>
                 <td>Type</td>
                 <td>Size</td>    
           </tr>
      <thead>
             <tr>
                 <td>Trailor</td>
                 <td>Life of Pi</td>
                 <td>350MB</td>    
           </tr>
           <tr>
                 <td>Total Recall</td>
                 <td>BDRIP</td>
                 <td>4.37GB</td>    
           </tr>


 <table>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want... leaving empty brackets in your desired state is under specifying your goal.

Comment: What do you want to have in `newArr[0]`? You have three candidates.

Comment: Why don't you define an object `Movie` with properties `Title`, `Type` and `Size`, and use an array of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Concat` if you just want to join all the arrays together:

```
arr1.Concat(arr2).Concat(arr3);
```

If you want a new two-dimensional array, then simply create and populate it:

```
var setOfArrays = new string[][] { arr1, arr2, arr3 };
```

---

**Edit** Access them using the same square-bracket syntax `setOfArrays[setIndex][itemIndex]`...

```
for (int i=0 ; i<setOfArrays.Length ; i++)
{
    for (int j=0 ; j<setOfArrays[i].Length ; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(setOfArrays[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List<string[]> is a type but used as a variable.

Comment: @BhushanFirake sorry, I had a typo in my answer -- please see my edit, should work now.

Comment: how an element can be accessed from this array then??

Comment: @BhushanFirake you can double the bracket syntax -- `setOfArrays[0][0]`, etc.

Comment: any suggestion to print it in a single table as described in the question

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier if you would create a class (or struct) for storing data. Much more understandable if you read it later:

```
class Record
{
    public String Title {get; set;}
    public String Type {get; set;}
    public String Size {get; set;}

    public Record(String title, String type, String size)
    {
        Title = title;
        Type = type;
        Size = size;
    }
}
```

And then just fill a list of those objects with your data:

```
List<Record> records = new List<Record>();

for(int i=0; i<elementcount; i++)
    records[i] = new Record(arr1[i], arr2[i], arr3[i]);
```

Comment: I agree that an object (I almost never use structs, as their value semantics in C# will surprise you in the worst ways) customized to the purpose often is a better representation.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I didn't use your HTML example, but this code shows you one viable technique:

```
void Main()
{
    var one = new string[] { "one", "two" };
    var two = new string[] { "apple", "pear" };
    var three = new string[] { "cat", "dog" };

    GroupFormatDemo(one, two, three);

}
void GroupFormatDemo(params string[][] args) 
{
    foreach (var a in args) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First={0}, Second={1}", a[0], a[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a class type to hold one element of data from each of the three arrays:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
    public string Item3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then construct an array of these objects, populating the fields with values from the original arrays:

```
var list = new List<Data>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
{
    list.Add(new Data() { Item1 = arr1[i], Item2 = arr2[i], Item3 = arr3[i] };
}

var dataArray = list.ToArray();
```

This loop assumes that arr1, arr2, and arr3 all have exactly the same length.

You can then access the data under one index, referring to the particular fields of interest:

```
Console.WriteLine(dataArray[x].Item1, dataArray[x].Item2, dataArray[x].Item3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on the problem with a LINQ Solution.This will produce a single array ,with elements on the same index joined together.

```
List<string[]> movies = new List<string[]>() {arr1, arr2, arr3};


var mergedArray = movies.Aggregate((sArrOne, sArrtwo) => 
                               sArrOne.Zip(sArrtwo, (one, two) => one += " "+two)
                        .ToArray());
```

`mergedArray[0]`  --> Trailor Life of Pi 350MB